# Given an array contains sequence of numbers from 0 to 1000.

Tags: c#, arrays

Given an array contains sequence of numbers from 0 to 1000. Use for loop to sum the array values and BREAK the loop if the sum >= 500  C#

Comment: So, what's the problem? We are not just a coding service here.

Comment: I need to understand the source code for the example and see how

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
//first initialize your array

// Loop over array and do sum.
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i < yourArray.Length; i++)
{
    sum += yourArray[i];
    if(sum >=  500)
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Sum : {0}", sum); //print out your sum
```

**Here is a live [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/prpTL5)**

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed not one indexed!

Comment: @RichardSchneider sorry my mistake, I updated my answer, undo your downvote

Comment: Yea Richard not indexed..

Comment: @AmoreMadeik you're welcome

Comment: wait i will create a quick demo for you

Comment: @Richard Schneider .. thx again bro ..

Comment: @Luthando Loot  ... i Love You .. hahaha thx again bro ..

Comment: @AmoreMadeik i added a demo for you

Comment: I wish people could leave a comment when downvoting!

Comment: @Luthando Loot .. thx bro i was see demo .. thx again ..

Comment: @AmoreMadeik if this has solved your question please mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself

Answer (score -2):

```
static void Bouns()
    {

        int []ar=new int[1000];
            int sum = 0;
            for (int counter = 1; counter < ar.Length; counter++)
            {
                sum += ar[counter];
                if (sum >= 500)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(ar[counter]);
            }

    }
```

Comment: now i cant print array values ??

Comment: @ Luthando Loot       @ Richard Schneider